# How to access javascript bookmarklet in firefox in javascript

Tags: javascript, mozilla, bookmarklet

I have made javascript bookmarklet for firefox. Now i want to access it in javascript like other document/ DOM elements are accessed through their id or class. Please anybody tell me how i can access my javascript bookmarklet . Actually i want to make it blink /change it color by accessing it.

My bookmarklet code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="toolbar" >
<a id='button' href='javascript:alert("my bookmarklet");' 
>Lysted</a>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now i want to access bookmarklet in "script tags/ javascript". Please please help anybody

Comment: Do you want to access the user's bookmarklets from a web page? The question is not entirely clear, what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: ok i edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: @RobW now please help

Comment: Something like `alert( $('a[href^="javascript:"').attr('href') )` ..? Can you explain what you want to achieve (give a concrete example), tell what you've tried to achieve this goal, and explain where and how you're stuck?

Comment: i dont know how to access i am new to bookmarklet

Comment: @wumm i want access my own made bookmarklet not other ones and accessing it where i make it .. there is no way??

Comment: Like if any one want to change it color / want to blink it .like that one